# Test failing only on travis-ci; RTTI not supported?

Tags: c++, inheritance, travis-ci, undefined-behavior, dynamic-cast

I've got a fairly simple test that's failing on travis-ci continuous integration servers but I cannot reproduce the failure. It almost appears as if RTTI is not supported on the CI server but as far as I know it's not possible to turn off RTTI on gcc.

I'm wondering if I am relying on undefined behavior here and that's what's causing the discrepancy. Can anyone tell me why this might fail inconsistently?

```cpp
#include <catch.hpp>

template <typename T, typename U>
T * As(U * Object)
{
    return dynamic_cast<T *>(Object);
}

class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{};


{
    // in tests...
    Derived b;

    REQUIRE(As<Derived>((Base*)&b) == &b);
}
```

The above test always passes when I run on a variety of architectures, but fails on travis-ci with the following expansion:

```
__null == 0x00007ffd6d95fe70
```

so `As<Derived>((Base*)&b)` is returning `null` while I expect it
to return some non-null value. We can obviously see that `b` is actually a `Derived` instance - am I doing something wrong with my various casts and dereferences?

Comment: Did you check if you are using the same gcc version than Travis? If not, this is not surprising that you observe a difference behavior on your machine...

Comment: @Thomas g++ 4.6.3 on travis-ci and g++ 4.8.2 on my test machine. I'll see if I can get a matching system set up to test. But I still don't see how the results of this could be different, even on a different version of gcc.

Comment: Maybe RTTI is not on by default in 4.6.3, have you tried turning it on explicitly with `-frtti`?

Comment: Also, your example code shouldn't even compile. `As<T>(...)` receives and returns a reference, but you call it with a pointer and compare the result to a pointer...

Comment: What about trying in ideone your example on different gcc versions and see what it tells you?

Comment: @melak47 I'll never learn to compile my snippets... I had copied the wrong overload of `As`. Newly edited could should be correct.

Comment: @ThomasMoulard I just tried 4.3.2 and 4.9.2 on ideone and both executed as I expected them to. My precise server is almost set up so I should have results from the exact g++ that is being used on travis shortly.

Comment: Is the problem happening on all builds? If it is, could you isolate this issue in a separate repo and see what Travis people are saying? Maybe your Travis yaml file is passing an unexpected flag to gcc?

Comment: @ThomasMoulard Success! err... Failure! I spun up a 12.04 server and the test failure repros there. That'll make this a lot easier to figure out - thanks for the help.

Comment: As I suppose is to be expected, the answer was outside of the code I posted - another compilation unit had it's own Base and Derived classes and when linked it caused a conflict. Changing the name of the classes solved the issue.

Comment: @iondune -- post that as an answer and I'll upvote it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this as a comment on the question but figured it should be in the answers section. It turns out I had multiple compilation units with classes called `Base` and `Derived` and when linked it caused a conflict. Changing the name of the classes solved the issue.